# Error bar for Poisson count data

Tags: confidence-interval, poisson-distribution, fitting, count-data

I have a set of data, counts versus time. 
The whole data looks like this

[image: data]

Here is a sample

```
       x     y
    [ -0.9   0. ]
    [ -0.8   4. ]
    [ -0.7   5. ]
    [ -0.6   1. ]
    [ -0.5   9. ]
    [ -0.4   8. ]
    [ -0.3  10. ]
    [ -0.2   9. ]
    [ -0.1  18. ]
    [  0.   25. ]
    [  0.1  24. ]
    [  0.2  26. ]
    [  0.3  18. ]
    [  0.4  32. ]
    [  0.5  25. ]
    [  0.6  32. ]
    [  0.7  20. ]
    [  0.8  23. ]
    [  0.9  16. ]
```

I want to generate suitable error bars for the y-axis in this data. Some people in my research area use the following:

$$y \pm \sqrt{y}$$

or

$$y \pm y\sqrt{\frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{\bar{y}}}$$

Because the data is meant to be Poisson, however this doesn't make sense to me because surely
for larger y-values, aka more counts...the error should get smaller, not bigger.

Comment: I wonder about the sense in which you mean "error." Eg, a Poisson(1) variate will typically have values between 0 and 4, whereas a Poisson(100) variate will typically have values between 80 and 120 or so. Obviously the latter has larger errors, but *on a relative basis* the former has the larger ones (from -100% to +300% or so, versus -20% to +20%). As far as the second part of your question goes, it is too broad to be answered because there are too many issues to address. Please search our site for keywords including [tag:poisson], [tag:generalized-linear-model], and [tag:change-point].

Comment: Ok Ill scrap the second part for now, any if I need to Ill make it into a new question. For the first part, are you saying that the formula's I have ill give a true representation of the relative error